# C Lua Api works with lua5.1 but not with qlua interpreter

Tags: lua, lua-c++-connection, qlua

I am using Lua for a deep learning task and my main interpreter is **qlua**. I need to get image stream from C based application. For this to happen I need to interface Lua with C to get access to the image stream. I went through a couple of C Lua Api tutorials and found this one working with Lua5.1 perfectly. 
[lua c wrapping](https://chsasank.github.io/lua-c-wrapping.html).

The problem is that when I use qlua as interpreter for this code it does not work and gives me the following errors:

**LUA CODE**

```
require "power"
print(square(1.414213598))
print(cube(5))
```

**ERRORS**

```
/home/brainy/LuaCApiTest/CallCfromLua/hellofunc.lua:5: module 'power' not found:
    no field package.preload['power']
    no file './power.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/luajit-2.0.4/power.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/power.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/power/init.lua'
    no file './power.lua'
    no file './power/init.lua'
    no file './lua/power.lua'
    no file './lua/power/init.lua'
    no file '/opt/zbstudio/lualibs/power/power.lua'
    no file '/opt/zbstudio/lualibs/power.lua'
    no file '/opt/zbstudio/lualibs/power/power/init.lua'
    no file '/opt/zbstudio/lualibs/power/init.lua'
    no file './power.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/power.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
    no file '/opt/zbstudio/bin/linux/x64/libpower.so'
    no file '/opt/zbstudio/bin/linux/x64/clibs/power.so'
    no file '/opt/zbstudio/bin/linux/x64/clibs/libpower.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    /home/brainy/LuaCApiTest/CallCfromLua/hellofunc.lua:5: in main chunk
```

What would be the solution to get this working with qlua interpreter?

Comment: Looks like the same error as this: https://github.com/torch/qtlua/issues/7 - i.e. you need to set `package.path`.

Comment: Yup that did the job. Thanks John.